# Can Evolution be configured to delete invitations when I click Accept?

Tags: evolution, calendar

I am switching from Outlook on Win7 to Evolution on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

One of the things I found very handy in Outlook, was that when you accept or tentatively accept or decline a meeting invitation, the calendar is updated and the invitation is deleted(put in the trash).

In Evolution the calendar is updated but the invitation remains in the inbox, so you have to delete it manually afterwards.

So the question is: Is there any way to configure Evolution to also delete the invitation once you have responded to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently discovered how to do this. I am not sure whether this option was there before, or if it came with an update. Anyhow for version 3.18.5.2 it is as simple as:

1. Open *Evolution Preferences* (*Edit → Preferences* or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).
2. Select *Calendar and Tasks* on the left.
3. Select the *Meeting Invitations* tab.
4. Tick the *Delete message after acting* checkbox.

Comment: Nice. Be sure to accept your answer to resolve the question.